# Memory Use Errors on Importing many products into WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, woocommerce

I have developed a WordPress plugin that integrates with WooCommerce.  Among other features, it facilitates importing of products from an external database.  There seems to be a threshold of around 900 where fewer products work without issue, but more than that crash with an out-of-memory error.  When I see an error in `debug.log` it points to the 'random' function that pushed the memory over the edge and is of little help.

Some of the directions I have tried:

- Made sure I am using the latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce and PHP 8
- I am working with Scheduled Actions to decouple this process from page loads.
- I tried adding [`wp_suspend_cache_addition(true)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_suspend_cache_addition/) without a noticeable difference, thinking that maybe WordPress/WooCommerce are storing product data in a memory cache that I do not need.
- I have added memory monitoring debugging code but have learned little other than the memory used slowly increases until the crash.

My main limitation is that this needs to work within a plugin for WordPress/WooCommerce so I can not assume to have access to the server itself.  In addition, I would like to refrain from direct database insertion and use WP/WC functions for the obvious reasons.

How do WordPress and WooCommerce handle these sort of imports of data?  What memory management do they employ?  It looks to me like WooCommerce ultimately calls `wp_update_post()` or `wp_insert_post()` and those functions ultimately call `$wpdb->update()` or `$wpdb->insert()` which do the actual database insertions, and it doesn't seem like there is any caching going on there.

Another place for a memory leak might be a check if the product already exists in the database.  I set that up using `WP_Query`, and found that by using `get_posts()` I think I can reduce the memory used by some.  But the issue still persists.

EDIT:
It seems that if I run the process in batches/paging from within PHP using Scheduled Actions, I get the same results.  However if I run the batches from JS via AJAX, it looks like it processes all the products correctly. This means I can run an import from the browser, but not automated from the backend.

EDIT2:
Here is some of the code I'm running.  I have edited it down as much as I could to keep it simple without loosing any of the important things.  (A lot of error checking/reporting is gone, and some variables replaced with strings to make things simpler without loosing context)  If there is something missing or unclear, please let me know.

```
    function my_update_product_listings() {

    //Returns an array of Simple Products, Products with Variations and Variations
    $products = my_apiCall( "GET", "API/URL/Sanitized/For/StackOverflow" );

    if ( is_wp_error( $products ) ) {
        return array( 'message' => "Product Update Error" );
    } 
    
    //Update/insert products
    //Return the number of inserts and updates and IDs of errors
    $updated = my_update_products( $products );

    //Remove Variable Products and error products
    //We only update Price and Inventory on Simple Products or Variations
    $end_products = my_only_end_products($products, $updated);

    //Run Price update and Inventory update functions on End Products
    do_action( 'post_update_end_products_actions_filter', $end_products);

    return "complete";
}

function my_single_products( $products ) {
    if ( !$updated ) {
        $updated = array('new' => 0, 'existing' => 0, 'errors' => array());
    }

    foreach ( $products as $prod ) {

        $prod_sku = $prod['sku'];
        $parent = $prod['parent'];
        $object_term  = $parent ? 'variable' : 'simple';
        
        $variation = $prod['parent_sku'] && !$parent;
    
        try {
            $existing = my_is_already_product( $prod_sku, $variation );
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            $updated["errors"][] = $prod_sku;
            continue;
        }

        $meta_input = array(
            '_visibility'   => 'visible',
            '_manage_stock' => 'yes',
            '_backorders'   => 'no',
            '_downloadable' => 'no',
            '_featured'     => 'no',
            '_virutal'      => 'no',
            '_sku'          => $prod_sku,
        );
        
        if ( $parent ) {
            $meta_input['_manage_stock'] = "no";
        }

        $post_info = array(
            'post_type'  => "product",
            'meta_input' => $meta_input,
            'post_title' => $prod['description'];
        );

        if ( $existing ) {
            $post_info['ID'] = $existing;
            
            $post_id = wp_update_post( $post_info, true );
        } else {
            $post_info['post_status'] = 'draft';
            $post_info['post_name']   = "p_" . $prod_sku;
            
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_info, true );
        }

        if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
            $updated['errors'][] = $prod_sku;
        } else {
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $object_term, 'product_type' );
            $product    = wc_get_product( $post_id );
            $attributes = array();
            foreach ( $prod as $key => $value ) {
                //Attributes from database are fields that begin with 'SPEC' followed by a number
                if ( str_starts_with( $key, "SPEC" ) && $value != null ) {
                    $attributes['pa_' . strtolower( $key )] = array(
                        'name'       => 'pa_' . strtolower( $key ),
                        'value'      => strtolower( urldecode( $value ) ),
                        'is_visible' => 1
                    );
                }
            }
            if ( $attributes ) {
                $product->update_meta_data( '_product_attributes', $attributes );
            }

            if ( $existing ) {
                $updated['existing']++;
            } else {
                $updated['new']++;
            }

            $product->update_meta_data( 'my_custom_synced_meta_field', 1 );
            $product->save();
        }
    }

    return $updated;
}

function my_is_already_product( $sku, $variation ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => '_sku',
            'value' => $sku
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'my_custom_synced_meta_field',
            'value' => 1
        )
    );

    $gotten_posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'   => $variation ? 'product_variation' : 'product',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'meta_query'  => $meta_query
    ));

    if ( count($gotten_posts) === 0 ) {
        return false;
    } else if ( count($gotten_posts) === 1 ) {
        return $gotten_posts[0]->ID;
    } else if ( count($gotten_posts) > 1 ) {
        throw new Exception( "Multiple products found with same SKU: ". $sku );
    }
}

function my_update_product_price( $products_prices ) {
    $price_list      = get_option( "my_price_list" );
    $sale_price_list = get_option( "my_sale_price_list" );

    $priceField = 'price';

    foreach ( $products_prices as $prices ) {
        if ( !isset( $prices['prices'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $product = my_get_product_by_SKU( $prices['sku'] );
        if ( $product ) {
            foreach ( $prices['prices'] as $pricePoint ) {
                if ( $pricePoint['priceList'] === $price_list ) {
                    $product->set_regular_price( $pricePoint['price'] );
                }
                if ( $pricePoint['priceList'] === $sale_price_list ) {
                    $product->set_sale_price( $pricePoint['price'] );
                }
            }
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}

function my_get_product_by_SKU( $sku, $variable = false ) {
    try {
        $id = my_is_already_product( $sku );
        if ( $id ) {
            if ( $variable ) {
                $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $id );
            } else {
                $product = new WC_Product( $id );
            }
        } else {
            $id = my_is_already_product( $sku, true );
            if ( $id ) {
                $product = new WC_Product_Variation( $id );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $product;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        error_log( "Get Product by SKU Error: " . $e->getMessage() );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing your scheduled actions hook code will help understand the issue, if you're not chucking your import number per batch and trying to import all products at once then it will bring the memory issues.

Comment: @VijayHardaha - Can you elaborate on what you mean by "chucking your import number"?

Comment: By **chucking** I meant, take 10-15 records from your total records and process that with 1 batch with scheduled actions and then in the next batch take another 10-15 and then process those.

Comment: @VijayHardaha - See the edit above.  Splitting the data into chunks only partially helps.

Comment: Without the code, I can't tell what you're doing wrong or what should be changed in your code.